# .rotate! throws NoMethodError in before_create method, but .rotate does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.7

In my model, I have:

```
  after_initialize :populate_neutral_post_option
  before_create :make_neutral_option_last

  module RequiredOptions
    NEUTRAL = "Neutral"
  end

  def populate_neutral_post_option
    if self.new_record? && post_options.map(&:text).exclude?(RequiredOptions::NEUTRAL)
      post_options.build(text: RequiredOptions::NEUTRAL)
    end
  end

  def make_neutral_option_last
    post_options.rotate!(1)
  end
```

And I get a NoMethodError saying `.rotate!` is undefined. Plain old `.rotate` without the bang works fine, but I want the result to be saved in the original array.

The goal is to have this "Neutral" post option appear last in a list. I can call `.rotate` on the array in the view, but this seems like unnecessary repetitive work when I should probably just alter the original array, right? Any advice?

Running ruby 2.7.0p0

Comment: What Ruby version are you running?

Comment: ruby 2.7.0p0 - I will add that to question.

Comment: This is hard to answer without the error message.

Comment: Can you check the class of `post_options`?

Comment: Relations are not arrays, Rails does some magic to make array methods available to your relations. But, You can't use bang version of array methods with active record relations